# Change column name based on named vector (R)

Tags: r, vector, columnsorting

I have the following dataframe:

```
   a b c d e f g h i j
   1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
   1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
   1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
   1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

And the following vector (or dataframe)

```
sample     name
a          1
b          2
c          3
d          4
e          5
f          6
g          7
h          8
i          9
j          10
```

I want to rename the columns on the first dataframe, based on the second dataframe:

```
   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
   1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
   1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
   1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
   1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Answer (score 3):

We may use `match`

```
names(df1) <- df2$name[match(names(df1), df2$sample)]
```

-output

```
> df1
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1
2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1
3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1
4 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1
```

---

Or use a named vector to match

```
names(df1) <- setNames(df2$name, df2$sample)[names(df1)]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(a = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), b = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
    c = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), d = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), e = c(1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L), f = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), g = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), h = c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), i = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), j = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

df2 <- structure(list(sample = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", 
"h", "i", "j"), name = 1:10), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Comment: This works but it may cause problems. Whereas df1$a in the original data frame returns the first column, df1$1 in the returned version returns an error. To get the first column you will need df1$'1'.